# Print a sorted list

Tags: python

Why executing the following:

```
print([7,1,0].sort())
```

produces:

```
None
```

while executing the following:

```
a = [7,1,0]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

produces:

```
[0, 1, 7]
```

?

Comment: I'm not going to add another answer, but to state the current answers in a different way: `sort` modifies the list you give it, but doesn't return anything. `sorted` creates a copy of the list, sorts the copy, and returns the sorted copy. It leaves the original list unchanged.

Comment: And just a tip: I didn't downvote, but the downvote you do have is likely because this question could have been answered by checking the documentation. ***ALWAYS*** check the documentation if you're confused about the operation of a function. If you don't use an IDE that automatically shows the docs, you should have the Python documentation open in your browser while you write.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in the first example `print([7,1,0].sort())` you are printing value returned by `sort()` and `sort()` does not return anything.
While later you are performing `sort()` on the list `a` and then printing the list`a`.

`Sort()` changes order of elements in the list `a` and does not return anything.

Use `sorted()` to get sorted list as returned value.

Answer (score 3):

Because `.sort()` operates on the list and returns `None`, while `print(sorted(a))` prints what you want but does not alter the list

Answer (score 3):

`sort()` sorts the list but returns `None`.  You probably want `sorted`.

`print(sorted([7,1,0]))`

Answer (score 2):

The `.sort()` method sorts the list in place *and returns `None`*. The list becomes sorted, which is why printing the list displays the expected value. However, `print(x.sort())` prints the result of `sort()`, and `sort()` returns `None`.